# Split line based on date

Tags: text-processing

```
Thu_Jun_04_09:22:50_2020=abcd:some_string=Thu_Jun_04_09:39:54_2020=efgh:some_string=Thu_Jun_04_09:51:12_2020=ijkl:some_string,some_string
```

I have the above output but I want in below format.

```
Thu_Jun_04_09:22:50_2020=abcd:some_string
Thu_Jun_04_09:39:54_2020=efgh:some_string
Thu_Jun_04_09:51:12_2020=ijkl:some_string,some_string
```

Is there any way I can split the line based in the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have your input in `file`, you can do (GNU sed):

```
$ sed 's/=/\n/2;P;D' file
Thu_Jun_04_09:22:50_2020=abcd:some_string
Thu_Jun_04_09:39:54_2020=efgh:some_string
Thu_Jun_04_09:51:12_2020=ijkl:some_string,some_string
```

The `s/=/\n/2` will replace the second `=` with a `\n`, a newline. Then, the `P;` will print everything up to the first `\n` in the current pattern space (what is currently being read) and the `D` will empty the pattern space so we can start the process again. These are documented in `man sed`:

```
   D      If pattern space contains no newline, start a normal  new  cycle
          as  if  the d command was issued.  Otherwise, delete text in the
          pattern space up to the first newline, and  restart  cycle  with
          the  resultant  pattern space, without reading a new line of in‐
          put.
   P      Print  up  to  the first embedded newline of the current pattern
          space.
```

---

Alternatively, with GNU `grep`, you can do:

```
$ grep -oP '[^=]+=[^=]+' file
Thu_Jun_04_09:22:50_2020=abcd:some_string
Thu_Jun_04_09:39:54_2020=efgh:some_string
Thu_Jun_04_09:51:12_2020=ijkl:some_string,some_string
```

That will look for a stretch of non-`=` characters, followed by a `=` and then another stretch of non-`=`. The `-o` tells grep to only print the matching portion of the line, so the result is printing the groups you are looking for.

---

Yet another option would be to use `awk` with `=` as the input field separator, and just print the fields in pairs:

```
$ awk -F= '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2){print $(i-1)"="$i}} ' file
Thu_Jun_04_09:22:50_2020=abcd:some_string
Thu_Jun_04_09:39:54_2020=efgh:some_string
Thu_Jun_04_09:51:12_2020=ijkl:some_string,some_string
```

Comment: You are too quick. Thanks a lot. It worked for me

Comment: I have just edited the question and added the "some_string" in 2nd row can you check and help. Earlier answer did not work for I have any string attached after '='. I want to split the line only when the date found.

Comment: @Jeetu that is a completely different issue. I have rolled back your edit. Please post a new question, explain what date you are looking for (any date? a specific date?) and _exactly_ how we can know if an `=` is a field separator or part of the field.

Comment: I have posted the new question with "How to split lines only after date found" header

Answer (score 0):

```
$ tr '=' '\n' <file | paste -d '=' - -
Thu_Jun_04_09:22:50_2020=abcd:some_string
Thu_Jun_04_09:39:54_2020=efgh:some_string
Thu_Jun_04_09:51:12_2020=ijkl:some_string,some_string
```

This first replaces all `=` characters by newlines using `tr`, and then reformat that into two columns with `=` as the delimiter using `paste`.

---

With standard `sed`:

```
$ sed -e 'y/=/\n/' -e 's/\n/=/;P;D' file
Thu_Jun_04_09:22:50_2020=abcd:some_string
Thu_Jun_04_09:39:54_2020=efgh:some_string
Thu_Jun_04_09:51:12_2020=ijkl:some_string,some_string
```

This first replaces all `=` characters with newlines in the pattern space.  It then replaces the first newline with `=`, prints the initial part of the pattern space (up to the first newline), and then deletes the printed part.  It then restarts the cycle with the remaining data.

[Terdon's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/592456/116858) is what you would use if you have GNU `sed`, but it's not possible to portably *insert* a newline with the `s///` command in standard `sed`. The standard `y///` comand, however, has no issues inserting newlines.

Comment: I have this content "Thu_Jun_04_09:30:22_2020=some_string:some_string=Thu_Jun_04_09:32:04_2020=some_str:some_string=some_string=Thu_Jun_04_09:35:05_2020=some_str:some_string,some_str" content but it's not coming in the way I want. Its coming in below format
"Thu_Jun_04_09:30:22_2020=some_string:some_string
Thu_Jun_04_09:32:04_2020=some_str:some_string
some_string=Thu_Jun_04_09:35:05_2020
some_str:some_string,some_str"

Comment: @Jeetu Yes, I'm not surprised. That data is different from what you showed in the question. It contains `some_str:some_string=some_string`, which you had no instance of in the data in the question.  Both mine and terdon's answers would fail with that data.